# Are orthogonal vectors rotated through Euler rotations still orthogonal?

Tags: vectors

I am using three orthogonal vectors to characterize the orientation of a sensor and when I perform euler rotations on these sets of vectors the resultant vectors are not orthogonal. Does this mean there is an error in my rotation algorithm or is my understanding flawed?

Comment: Rotated as a group they should stay orthogonal.  Imagine 3 orthogonal vectors like the corner of a cube.  Rotating that cube in space doesn't change anything about how the vectors relate to each other.

Comment: There is an error in your rotation algorithm. You're correct that they should still be orthogonal after rotation.

Comment: Many of the 6 or 10 DOF devices output a Quaternion. Are you doing the math right?